# Play HLS segments through Media source extensions

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video

I got a list of `m4s` and `init.mp4` from this FFMPEG command

```
ffmpeg -i bunny.mp4 -f hls -hls_segment_type fmp4 -c:v copy playlist.m3u8
```

I  send those chunks using `Socket`and try to play them through MSE. 
When i send them in this order:

```
init.mp4 + playlist0.m4s + playlist1.m4s ...
```

They play without any problem, But when i want to start from the chunk number 3 meaning `init.mp4 + playlist3.m4s` for example i get this error:

```
video frame with PTS 0us has negative DTS -80000us after applying timestampOffset, handling any discontinuity, and filtering against append window.
```

I want to be able to start from any chunk, currently the only way to play the video is to star by `init.mp4 + playlist0.m4s` meaning `playlist0.m4s` because `init.mp4` contain just headers of the video, This is the client code i'm using :

```
var socket = io();
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64000d,mp4a.40.2"'; // true
if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) 
{
    var mediaSource = new MediaSource;
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function () {
            var mediaSource = this;
            var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
           sourceBuffer.mode = 'segments'; 
            sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function (_) { video.play().then(function() { }).catch(function(error) { }); });
            socket.on('broadcast', function (chunk) {
                downloadData(chunk.uri, function(arrayBuffer) {
                    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
                });
            });
    });
} else {
    console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
}
function downloadData(url, cb) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('get', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        cb(new Uint8Array(xhr.response));
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Is this in [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=398141)?

Comment: Did you get this working?